# Can't access / trigger .then from promise in unit test

Tags: angular, promise, karma-jasmine

I have this code I want to test:

```
public renderPage(page: number) {
    return this.pdfVar.getPage(page).then((page: any) => {
      console.log('PAGE', page);
      let viewport = page.getViewport(1);
      let container = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('div');
      let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');

      if (!this.originalSizeVar) {
        viewport = page.getViewport((this.element.nativeElement.offsetWidth * 1)  / (viewport.width * 1));
      }

      if (!this.showAllVar) {
        this.removeAllChildNodes(container);
      }

      container.appendChild(canvas);

      canvas.id = 'pdfCanvas';
      canvas.height = viewport.height;
      canvas.width = viewport.width;

      let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      page.render({
        canvasContext: context,
        viewport: viewport
      });
    });
```

This is my test:

```
it('render page',
    inject(
      [
        PdfViewerComponent
      ],
      (
        component: PdfViewerComponent
      ) => {
        component.pdfVar = mockPdfVar;
        let something = component.renderPage(2);
        something.then((data) => data());

      }
    )
  );
```

My coverage report says the callback located in .then is never executed. 
I tried various things but the callback function is never executed.
How can I trigger this part?

Angular2 version: RC5
Angular-CLI version: webpack.2

Answer (score 0):

You might need

```
return something.then((data) => data());
```

for the test runner to be able to wait for your test to complete.

Comment: I added this line in my test but it doesn't trigger it I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't know what Angular2 version you're using and what't the current way to use them. This changed with almost any update. Try to additionally wrap `inject` with `async? like `async(inject(...))`

Comment: I edited the OP with the version, async didn't do the trick either =/

Comment: In this example https://github.com/angular/angular/blame/99989f5d3fc4543743e870b781ae687deb4cf7af/modules/%40angular/facade/test/async_spec.ts they inject `AsyncTestCompleter` and call `done()` on it. This would be `something.then((data) => data()).then(_ => async.done())`.

Comment: I can't import AsyncTestCompleter, the testing_internal doesn't exist. Tried other packages but no luck there.